# What is the asymptotic complexity of $\log x / \log(1+1/x)$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

I have encountered the function $$f(x) = \frac{\log x}{\log(1+\frac{1}{x})}$$ in the context of computational complexity and am wondering whether it is possible to simplify it. In particular, I am wondering if
$$\Theta(f) = x \log x$$
which seems plausible from looking at [its graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/onbytg7dqp). If so, how to prove it - and if not, is there a more succinct way to represent $\Theta(f)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\log(1+u)\sim u$ when $u\to 0$, we have:

$$\frac{\log x}{\log(1+1/x)}\sim\frac{\log x}{1/x}=x\log x$$

when $x\to\infty$.